# Как подключить принтер Epson LQ-570 ESCP2 через переходник USB-LTP (VEN12)?

Tags: принтер, ubuntu

У меня стоит Ubuntu 10.04 на ноутбуке, при подключении принтере через переходник Ven12 не находит ничего (на ХР без проблем). Я захожу Система-Администрирование-Печать, но в окошке не находит его. Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с этим переходником в Linux-е?

Comment: Поставьте (обновите) современный дистр.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ничего общего с программированием.

Answer (score 1):

Ну по логике вещей необходимо найти драйвер к мосту USB-to-LPT